# why other classes like BigInteger in jdk7 does not use "avoid getfield opcode" tech just like String.trim

Tags: jvm, opcode

why the BigInteger does not use local variable to avoid getfield opcode ?

mag in BigInteger and value in String are all final.

BigInteger's source and opcode

[image]

String.trim's source

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of asking why it doesn't do that, you should ask *Why would one do that in the first place?*, considering that requires extra code and clarifying comments.

Those micro-optimizations are generally *not* necessary because saving on an opcode only reduces the bytecode size of the method, which in turn mostly affects the interpreter and early inlining decisions by the JITs. Or put differently it does not really affect the generated assembly once the code gets hot enough to be JITed because the compilers will be able to see that those loads all refers to the same variable.

String is a very important class in the JVM, where such tiny optimizations might improve startup speed a little bit.

BigInteger on the other hand is not important to JVM startup and if you use it frequently this will get optimized away by the JITs anyway, interpreter performance is generally not relevant to BigInt use-cases.

Comment: So if I wanna know more about opcode optimized, I always have to be involved in JIT . Right?

Comment: @IoriChina I suggest you look at JITWatch to see how the byte code is turned into native code, because for performance this is what really matters.